# Xamarin.Forms: Failed to retrieve infortmation from remote source

Tags: xamarin, nuget, xamarin.forms, nuget-package

Good Day Guys. I'm currently doing a Xamarin.Forms (Portable) Application. And I want to update my Xamarin.Forms Nuget Package to the latest version. From Version 2.3.0.49 to 2.3.0.107

However, when I tried to install it, I got this error saying

> Failed to retrieve infortmation from remote source 'http://nuget.syncfusion.com/xamarin/FindPackagesById()?id='Xamarin.Forms'.

I checked all my packages and there's no **Syncfusion** installed.

What do you think is the reason behind this?

Thanks a lot.

Comment: Check your nuget sources config.  It sounds like you!re missing the official nuget source.

Comment: @Jason Oh thanks. Where can I find that Sir?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you are using Xamarin Studio, click the Xamarin Studio menu and then Preferences. Find the NuGet node and click the Sources node.

[image: Sources node]

The source like in the image should be present. If there is a SyncFusion one and you're not using it, you can remove it if you like.

If you're using Visual Studio (2015) go to Tools, Options and then enter NuGet in the search box. Now click the Package Sources and also ensure that the official NuGet feed is in there. You can uncheck other sources to see if that helps instead of deleting them.

[image: Visual Studio NuGet sources]

Comment: Thanks Sir. I'm using Visual Studio but I still manage to find that part. I've unchecked the Syncfusion and install the Xamarin.Forms. It worked :)

Comment: Added Visual Studio variant as well, glad to hear!